# How to Integrate 2 Different Magento Store For Products

Tags: products

We have 2 Magento sites on different domains and servers. We don't use any ERP or backend integration right now.

What i want to do is, i want to integrate this 2 magento store's products, stocks. Basically; everything about products.

So how can we do this?

I searched for extensions, dropshipping solutions and many other things but im confused at this position right now.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that is to either create some sort of synchronization process, or bring both Magento stores into the same Magento installation, utilizing Magento's website and store logic to separate them.